# Visual Studio 2017 & Resharper 2016.3 Errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I just installed VS17 Community and Resharper 2016.3 into it.  I'm working on a web project that was being maintained in VS13.  Everything was fine until I installed `Microsoft.CodeCom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` from NuGet (I wanted to upgrade the project to C# 6.0.

Now Resharper is reporting 2,429 errors within my project, when the project compiles just fine.

I have done all the "clear cache", "suspend/resume" and restarting VS17 tricks I know and could find on the internet.  Nothing has helped this issue.

It looks like the `Microsoft.CodeCom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` installs Roslyn which I have read has a lot of functional redundancy with Resharper.  Could that be part of the issue?

Is it possible to take advantage of C# 6.0 without destroying Resharper in this environment?

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest installing ReSharper 2017 EAP.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The reason is the lightweight loading technic for project files in vs 2017. Build your project and then click on "Reanalyze All" in R#: "Errors/Warnings in Solution"

Comment: Unfortunately for me, I have re-built my project and attempted to re-analyze from Resharper.  It didn't help.  It appears the problem was that it was overkill to install `Microsoft.CodeCom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`. All I had to do was set Resharper's C# language level to 6.0.  VS17 natively supports C# 6.0 in its compiler.  I have to do some more testing before verifying this.

Comment: Do you use MSBuild or "ReSharper Build"?

Comment: Errr...  Ummm...  Where is that set? SO the latest is that I uninstalled `Microsoft.CodeCom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` from my project.  Now my interpolated formatted strings won't compile. :(

Comment: It would appear my issue is that I am working with a "WebSite" project, which limits my options for newer development features.

Answer (score 0):

Have similar issue, problem resolved by setting "Lightweight solution load" in solution properties to False.

VS 2017 Community (Stable, not RC), Resharper 2016.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Posting for anybody else running into trouble...

I did all of these suggestions, even tried reinstalling resharper ultimate- nothing worked, was still suggesting errors/warnings and my solution was building fine.

I disabled lightweight solution load and clicked Build -> Run Code Analysis on Solution and it eliminated all the errors/warnings. Looking into if some of my settings from previous VS versions didn't make it into VS17.